# Updating a table basing on its date column in comparison to the date column of another table

Tags: sql-server

I am working on SQL Server. I have two tables as below:

Table A

```
Id  startdate       enddate       rating 
---------------------------------------- 
XYZ 6/12/18 2:55    6/12/18 2:57    NULL  
XYZ 7/20/18 21:44   7/20/18 21:45   NULL  
XYZ 8/30/18 9:51    8/30/18 9:52    NULL  
XYZ 9/27/18 3:45    9/27/18 3:47    NULL  
XYZ 9/27/18 9:29    9/27/18 9:32    NULL  
XYZ 11/1/18 7:00    11/1/18 7:02    NULL  
XYZ 11/13/18 2:38   11/13/18 3:13   NULL  
XYZ 11/13/18 15:52  11/13/18 15:54  NULL  
XYZ 11/26/18 12:14  11/26/18 12:16  NULL  
XYZ 12/10/18 12:12  12/10/18 12:25  NULL  
XYZ 12/12/18 10:24  12/13/18 10:41  NULL
```

Table B:

```
Id  startdate         enddate          rating  
---------------------------------------------
XYZ 9/5/18 2:33 PM      9/5/18 2:46 PM      7  
XYZ 9/14/18 12:41 AM    9/14/18 12:42 AM    6  
XYZ 12/8/18 1:36 PM     12/8/18 1:41 PM     8  
XYZ 12/15/18 1:04 AM    12/15/18 1:06 AM    7
```

I need to update rating of Table A by comparing the date columns of table with Table A. 
Basically, the date from table A which fall before the date in table B has to be updated with the rating from table B. Scenario is as follows:

1. minimum date in table B is 2018-09-05 and the first three columns in table A are less than this date. Hence, table B rating of 7 has to be updated to first three rows of table A.
2. Second minimum date in table B is 2018-09-14 and the fourth column in table A has date greater than this. Hence, this rating from table B is not updated in table A.
3. Third minimum date in table B is 2018-12-08 and the columns in table A from 4th to 10th has dates less than this date. Hence, rating of 8 from table B has to be updated in table A.

Result table A should be as follows:

```
Id  startdate       enddate          rating  
----------------------------------------------
XYZ 6/12/18 2:55 AM     6/12/18 2:57 AM     7  
XYZ 7/20/18 9:44 PM     7/20/18 9:45 PM     7  
XYZ 8/30/18 9:51 AM     8/30/18 9:52 AM     7  
XYZ 9/27/18 3:45 AM     9/27/18 3:47 AM     8  
XYZ 9/27/18 9:29 AM     9/27/18 9:32 AM     8  
XYZ 11/1/18 7:00 AM     11/1/18 7:02 AM     8  
XYZ 11/13/18 2:38 AM    11/13/18 3:13 AM    8  
XYZ 11/13/18 3:52 PM    11/13/18 3:54 PM    8  
XYZ 11/26/18 12:14 PM   11/26/18 12:16 PM   8  
XYZ 12/10/18 12:12 PM   12/10/18 12:25 PM   7  
XYZ 12/12/18 10:24 AM   12/13/18 10:41 AM   7
```

Need to handle the order of dates and avoid repeating the already considered columns as per condition. How to handle this case?

Comment: Please format your post as no one can make sense of it like that https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: When you say columns, do you mean rows?

Comment: Which dates are you looking at in your rule? The start date or the end date? I would assume the logic is "ir a row from table a has an end date that is between table B's end date on row N-1 and table B's end date on row N, update table A's rating with the rating from table B'a row N" but because both tables have multiple dates it's not obvious (and doesn't seem possible to deduce from your desired result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your requirement, you need to update with the nearest date matching condition, for this you need to update based on the order of the dates, otherwise you can get unexpected results.

You can use `CROSS APPLY`, to updated based on the order of the dates like following query.

```
update t1
set t1.rating =t2.rating
from tablea t1 
cross apply
(
 select top 1 rating from tableb tb where tb.Id=t1.Id and tb.startdate >t1.enddate
 order by startdate
)t2
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/NJHJP12987)

**Output**

```
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| Id  | startdate               | enddate                 | rating |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-06-12 02:55:00.000 | 2018-06-12 02:57:00.000 | 7      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-07-20 21:44:00.000 | 2018-07-20 21:45:00.000 | 7      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-08-30 09:51:00.000 | 2018-08-30 09:52:00.000 | 7      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-09-27 03:45:00.000 | 2018-09-27 03:47:00.000 | 8      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-09-27 09:29:00.000 | 2018-09-27 09:32:00.000 | 8      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-11-01 07:00:00.000 | 2018-11-01 07:02:00.000 | 8      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-11-13 02:38:00.000 | 2018-11-13 03:13:00.000 | 8      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-11-13 15:52:00.000 | 2018-11-13 15:54:00.000 | 8      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-11-26 12:14:00.000 | 2018-11-26 12:16:00.000 | 8      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-12-10 12:12:00.000 | 2018-12-10 12:25:00.000 | 7      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
| XYZ | 2018-12-12 10:24:00.000 | 2018-12-13 10:41:00.000 | 7      |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------------+--------+
```